# Get thymeleaf html file with all includes

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Hy guys, I'm new to Thymeleaf, my goal is to have an endpoint which returns a String with the content of a html file. Should be easy, but that file html contains thymeleaf code and uses fragments from others files so using *Files.readString(path)* does not reach the goal.

How can I include them (I want to only include fragments, I don't have to process the file)?

That's what I've done till now:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/get-template-html")
public String getTemplateHTMLEndpoint() {
    
    String templateHtml = "Problems reading template.html";
    
    try {
        String stringPath = new ClassPathResource("templates/template.html").getFile().getPath();
        Path path = Path.of(stringPath);
        templateHtml = Files.readString(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return templateHtml;
    
}
```

But in another method where I process the file passing the context I got an error about the fragment "footer::footer"

```
    String templateHtml = callGetTemplateHTMLEndPoint();

    StringTemplateResolver stringTemplateResolver = new StringTemplateResolver();
    stringTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(stringTemplateResolver);
    
    Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariable("expenseReportPdf", expenseReportPdf);
    context.setVariable("expensePdf", expensePdfList);
    context.setVariable("expenseImg", jpgFile);
    context.setVariable("amountCompanyCurrency", amountCompanyCurrency);
    context.setVariable("expenseIncurredList", expenseIncurredList);
    context.setVariable("expenseRiepiloghiList",expenseRiepiloghiList);
    context.setVariable("advancePayBigDecimal", advancePayBigDecimal);
    context.setVariable("dailyAllowanceList", dailyAllowanceList);
    context.setVariable("dailyAllowanceFlag", dailyAllowanceFlag);
    context.setVariable("logo",logo);
    context.setVariable("logoSmartex",logoSmartex);


    String renderedHtmlContent = templateEngine.process(templateHtml, context);
```

Comment: What have you tried exactly? If you just want to use Thymeleaf fragments with Spring Boot, you can look at one of my blog entries (e.g. https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/09/14/thymeleaf-iteration-and-fragments/) for an example that uses fragments.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a "standard" Spring Boot with Thymeleaf project (e.g. via https://start.spring.io), then the templates are automatically resolved if you put them in `src/main/resources/templates`

So if you created `src/main/resources/templates/templates.html`, then you can create a controller that will use that template like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController {

  @GetMapping("/get-template-html")
  public String getTemplateHtml() {
    return "templates"; // name of your template file without the .html extension
  }
}
```

If you start the application and access http://localhost:8080/get-template-html, you should see the HTML of the template.

Comment: Yes I know, ty but that is not what I want. I need an endpoint for retrieving it because different projects use that file

Comment: You want to get the _raw_ template without Thymeleaf processing so you can do a REST call from one project to another and re-use it? If so, can't you create a shared Java library?

Comment: Don't know, seems a good solution, I'm only doing what my boss said to me, I'm just an intern.